# Spark java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray cannot be cast to scala.collection.immutable.Seq

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dataframe (say df1) with the following structure

```
root
 |-- _1: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- groupByListStr: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Rank_Index: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Anomaly_Detection_Column: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Median_Value: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Mean_Value: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Lower_Limit: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Upper_Limit: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Computation_Type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Anomaly_Flag: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Anomaly_Type: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- _2: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- aggregator_Value: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- num_Elements: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- sum_Elements: double (nullable = true)
 |    |-- sum_Mean_Diff: double (nullable = true)
 |    |-- mean: double (nullable = true)
 |    |-- mean_AD: double (nullable = true)
 |    |-- lower_Limit: double (nullable = true)
 |    |-- upper_Limit: double (nullable = true)
 |    |-- anomaly_Col_List_Values: string (nullable = true)
```

This is how the data in column _1 looks like (mock data):

```
[[date, 1, 4.12, 3.32, 4.12, 4.1, 4.12, MEDIAN_COMPUTATION, false, 0], [date, 2, 5.12, 5.12, 3.12, 2.17,1.7, MEDIAN_COMPUTATION, false, 0]]
```

This is how column _2 looks like :

```
[date, 140, 6.519, 6.519, 4.66, 23763.63, 3.70, 5.62, 4.7_120_4.667_false|4.61_121_4.66_false|4.512_122_4.66_false|4.55_123_4.6_false|4.78924_124_4.6664_false]
```

Sample output :

```
--------------+----------+--------------------+-------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+------------------+------------+------------+------+----------+
|groupByListStr|Rank_Index|weekly_sales       |Median_Value       |Mean_Value          |Lower_Limit         |Upper_Limit         |Computation_Type  |Anomaly_Flag|Anomaly_Type|temp  |DUMMY_CLMN|
+--------------+----------+--------------------+-------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+------------------+------------+------------+------+----------+
|date          |11        |4.51                |4.71               |4.683               |3.60                |5.81                |MEDIAN_COMPUTATION|false       |0           |[date]|date      |
|date          |31        |3.71                |0.0                |4.67                |4.1                 |5.235               |MEAN_COMPUTATION  |false       |0           |[date]|date      |
```

I checkpointed this dataframe and used it for further transformation , like this :

```
spark.sparkContext.setCheckpointDir("/tmp")
val df=df1.checkpoint
val aggregatorListTemp=Seq("day")
val medianColumn="weekly_sales"
df.flatMap(x => x._1).
withColumn("temp", split($"groupByListStr", "\\|")).
select( col("*") +: (0 until (aggregatorListTemp.size)).
map(i => col("temp").getItem(i).as(aggregatorListTemp(i))): _*).
withColumnRenamed(anomalyDetectionColumnStr,medianColumn).
withColumn("Mean_Value", avg("Mean_Value") over (Window.partitionBy("groupByListStr",medianColumn,"Median_Value"))).distinct.persist
```

The type of df is  `Dataset[(Seq[ResultSetForEachKey], AnomalyRangeValues)]`
The case classes are as follows:

```
case class ResultSetForEachKey(groupByListStr : String, 
        Rank_Index: Int,
        Anomaly_Detection_Column: Double, 
        Median_Value: Double, 
        Mean_Value: Double, 
        Lower_Limit: Double,
        Upper_Limit: Double, 
        Computation_Type: String,
        Anomaly_Flag: Boolean,
        Anomaly_Type: Int)


 case class AnomalyRangeValues( 
        aggregator_Value: String, 
        num_Elements: Long, 
        sum_Elements: Double,
        sum_Mean_Diff: Double,
        mean: Double, 
        mean_AD: Double,
        lower_Limit: Double,
        upper_Limit: Double,
        anomaly_Col_List_Values: String)
```

This code runs fine in spark 2.3 but when I deployed it in an environment it throws an error in the line where the flatMap transformation occurs.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray  cannot be cast to scala.collection.immutable.Seq
```

I am unable to understand what is the issue and why it only fails in Spark 2.1

Comment: You must check the version of Spark present in the environment. If you have not been using that version on your local, you need to change that

Comment: Which Scala versions are you using locally and in the environment where you deploy?

Comment: both have  Scala 2.11.8

Comment: You should compile it with the same Spark version as the one where you deploy it.

Comment: can you post sample data ?

Comment: @Srinivas I have added the mock data in the question

Comment: also add expected output if you have any ?

Answer (score 0):

What is the type of df? Is it DataFrame that is Dataset[Row]. If so, I fail to see why it works at Spark 2.3 and why it compiles at all. flatMap accepts function from Row to TraversableOnce, but Row doesn't have _1.

In any case, with DataFrame I would use `df.select(explode($"_1") as  "smth")`, although it doesn't map struct fields to separate columns.

I am somewhat confused by your code.

Comment: @AyanBiswas do you know which transformation fails? I would try to isolate the problem by performing each transformation separately and probably adding show after each to force execution.
If it's flatMap then all the action after it are not relevant and just complicate the code